# Reading strings without function

Tags: c, string

```
>char str[20]="HELLO";
```

is correct, while

```
>char str[20];
>
str="HELLO";
```

isn't. WHY?

Answer (score 2):

```
char str[20]="HELLO";
```

The above is a *declaration* and also a *definition* of the identifier `str`, and has an *initializer*, `"HELLO"`. The C standard says about this *initialization*:

> An initializer specifies the initial value stored in an object.
>
> An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF−8 string
>   literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the
>   terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the
>   elements of the array.

```
char str[20];
str="HELLO";
```

The first line here is again a *declaration* and also a *definition* of the identifier `str`, but without an *initializer*. The second line is a statement with an *assignment* expression. The *constraint* for an *assignment* is:

> An assignment operator shall have a modifiable lvalue as its left operand.

Regarding lvalues, arrays, …:

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that
>   does not have array type, …

So, trying to assign to an array is a constraint violation.